# I want to get a javascript array from spring to list <String>

Tags: json

I want to get a JavaScript array from spring to list `<String>`.
I'm communicating with the server via dropzonejs.

So I coded it like this in javascript:

```
var rmvFileArr = new Array();
var src = $("#fileno"+fno+" img").attr('src');
rmvFileArr.push(src); 

this.on("sendingmultiple", function(file, xhr, formData){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("${_csrf.headerName}", "${_csrf.token}");
    formData.append("bcontent", document.getElementById("autosize").value);
    formData.append("user.uno", document.getElementById("uno").value);
    formData.append("mode", mode);
    var rmvArr = JSON.stringify(rmvFileArr);
    formData.append("rmvFileArr", rmvArr);
});
```

I sent the array to spring and printed the result

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Board {
     int bno;
     String bcontent;
         .
         .
         .
    List<String> rmvFileArr;
 }

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@ModelAttribute Board board) throws Exception{
     logger.info("filevo " + board.getRmvFileArr().get(0));
 }
```

I expected it to look like this:

```
filevo /inbyul/resources/images/postimages/1bc0e795-7f87-411d-b146-14f2bd5a5be1_2019092416491381.jpg
```

but the output is as follows:

```
filevo ["/inbyul/resources/images/postimages/1bc0e795-7f87-411d-b146-14f2bd5a5be1_2019092416491381.jpg"]
```

How can I get only the strings inside ""?

Comment: Could you show `JSON` payload sent to the server?

Comment: I'm sending data to a server using a FormData object.
What should I show you TT

To convert a FormData object to json:
ex)

Comment: {bcontent:"asd",
    user.uno:11, mode:"modify",
    rmvFileArr:["/inbyul/resources/images/postimages/1bc0e795-7f87-411d-b146-    14f2bd5a5be1_2019092416491381.jpg", "/inbyul/resources/images/postimages/7597ea7f-cfef-4d3b-bd59-e2a40d7203d4_2019092416491369.jpg"]}

Comment: It is a little bit strange that you see array brackets if you prints only `0-index` element. Are you sure you run on the server code you posted in a question? Can you debug it?

Comment: omg I solved it.
I deleted json.stringify And as follows I coded it.
`for(var i =0; i<rmvFileArr.length; i++){
       formData.append("rmvFileArr", rmvFileArr[i]);      }    `
Then only the strings in "" are bound. I don't think you should use that function. Thanks for trying to solve together !!!